# what is db.SaveChanges() in asp mvc4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

> I searched on many site about savechanges but i dont get any proper
>   answer can any one tell me about

1. `db.SaveChanges()`
2. `ModelState`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says : It persists all updates to the data source and resets change tracking in the object context.

Example

To save the changes made to the entities to a database, we need to call the ObjectContext class SaveChanges method. In the example given below, the query retrieves the first customer from the entityset -Customer.

```
var customer = context.Customer.First();
```

The context.Customer returns the Objectset of Customer types and the LINQ extension method First() returns only the first customer.

```
customer.FirstName = "Yasser";
customer.LastName = "Shaikh";

context.SaveChanges();
```

We can edit the first customer details like name and address by assigning new values to the properties and call the SaveChanges() method to save the changes back to the database.

During SaveChanges, the ObjectContext determines which fields were changed. In this example, only FirstName and LastName are changed. So, only those two values are sent into the command. To identify the row to be updated in the database, the ObjectContext uses the value of the EntityKey property.

Answer (score 1):

`db.SaveChanges()` is not part of ASP.NET MVC - it's part of Entity Framework which is a set of Object-Relational-Mapping (ORM) tools for the .NET Framework. All this method does is persist (save) data in some of your classes (entities) into a database.

Useful links:

- [Scott Gu - Code-First Development with Entity Framework 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx)
- [MSDN - Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework)

`ModelState` *is* a part of MVC and allows extra binding metadata to be passed from the Controller to the View, which is typically largely about validation.

Useful links:

- [MSDN - Model State Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)
- [MSDN - Performing Simple Validation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/performing-simple-validation-cs)

Answer (score 0):

Please read:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792(v=vs.110).aspx
2. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-(data)/performing-simple-validation-cs

This should help you a little. Basically the `db.SaveChanges()` method is used by Entity Framework to save current changes to the database and ModelState represents validation errors when e.g. the model is not valid.